# Socket connection disconnectd

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In windows phone 8 socket connection lost/disconnected when i am opening ContactChooserTask or PhotoChooserTask. how to set the socket connection keep-alive in windows phone silverlight applications.

Comment: Please share piece of your code snippet, if you can..?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/877454/Using-XMPP-and-Openfire-Server-in-Windows-Phone